# How can I enable touch input without having a touch device present?

Tags: windows-8-preview, touchscreen, input

I'm trying to find a way to enable touch style input in Windows 8. Specifically, I want to have the touch friendly user interface.

I'm looking at doing an experiment where I use a Wiimote for input, and I think the touch friendly user interface would make the experience much smoother.

I looked in my Control Panel, but I don't have the Pen and Touch thing, which makes me think I may need to add a fake input device of some kind to get Windows to do as I want.

Comment: have you tried installing a tablet driver, like one that would be used with, say, a wacom pen tablet? i assume your knowledge or programming is very great, so it shouldnt be that hard to modify a a driver there to work with a wiimote.

Comment: What are your hardware specs? Make and model?

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion to accomplish what you are looking for would be to turn on what is called "tablet mode".

In windows 10 you can do this by pushing the hotkeys (Windows + A) to open the action center.  Towards the bottom, one of the buttons is literally labeled "tablet mode".  Click that and you should have the touch interface you are looking for.  If it is greyed out that is due to having an "extended monitor" and that would have to be changed to get the button enabled.

In windows 8 you can do this by:
Clicking the Start button,
Open the Settings application,
Click on "System",
In the pane on the left of the screen scroll all the way to the bottom until you see "Tablet Mode",
Toggle this to on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect it to a touch screen or something like that, so once the drivers are installed the touch input will start to work

You can try to buy a cheap tablet or test it with a touch screen :)